# Printing values from array after I split the values?

Tags: java

I'm want to read in from a file and then split it into separate parts and then access it and print it out. I know i can't do it the way it looks now. Please reply asap. The object of the program is to read in from a file points where i split it into x and y values, then sort these values according to there polar_order(this i have figured out) i just want to print out the values for testing.
Thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        int count = 0;
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = read.nextInt();
        while(read.hasNext()){          
            String nN = read.nextLine();
            String[]cord = nN.split(" ");
            int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            count++;
        }
        read.close();

        for(int i = 0; i<N;i++){
            System.out.print(x[i]);

        }
```

Comment: -1 simply for "Please reply ASAP."  If you want someone to reply immediately to your question, you should hire an employee or a consultant, not ask on a peer question-and-answer forum.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are trying to print the contents of the string array 'cord'.
Try this code: 
string dataToPrint = string.Join(" ", cord);

Comment: cord does not exist in the for loop. It only exists in the while loop and string.Join(" ",cord) should be the exact same thing as printing nN

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you've structured your file but if you want to read in a file, here's an indication of how you might do that. Replace the while method with the method you need to extract the x, y values... you should probably apply Nist's answer to do so (use an ArrayList).

```
try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("your file path"));

        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(s.nextLine());
        }
        s.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the easiest way to print the contents of an array (assuming it's not null) is this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

For some odd reason, most of the list classes give nice output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

whereas arrays gives you a type/address indicator:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@10b62c9
```

I've never quite understood why they didn't do something so that arrays had nicer output without having to call some utility function.